# Liferay 7 - Freemarker: unwrap operation not matching the function signature

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-theme, liferay-7

I am facing an odd problem with Freemarker and the classloader that I did not use to have on 6.2.
Basically, there is a minor logic on the top of the template that uses Oauth. This use to work fine and I can't see a problem with it. I tried placing a variation of the Scribe everywhere I could, and even deleting the one that comes inside the ROOT.

What is odd is that the code successfully calls some methods before the exception is thrown, I guess then it is not a classloader problem but an issue with the unwrap operation. Did something change with regards to that functionality?

Code:

`${callbackParameters.add(TrueNTHOAuthConstants.REDIRECT, portalUtil.getCurrentCompleteURL(request))}

<#assign trueNTHConnectLoginURL = trueNTHConnect.getAuthorizationUrl(companyId,1, callbackParameters) /> (Exception at this line)`

`FreeMarker template error:
No compatible overloaded variation was found; can't convert (unwrap) the 3rd argument to the desired Java type.
The FTL type of the argument values were: number (wrapper: f.t.SimpleNumber), number (wrapper: f.t.SimpleNumber), extended_hash+string (org.scribe.model.ParameterList wrapped into f.e.b.StringModel).
**The matching overload was searched among these members**:
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy799.getAuthorizationUrl(long),
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy799.getAuthorizationUrl(long, int, org.scribe.model.ParameterList, org.scribe.model.ParameterList),
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy799.getAuthorizationUrl(long, int, org.scribe.model.ParameterList)`

I have just mentioned the classloader as I had to deal with several ClassNotFoundException or class definition not found to get to this point. This was somehow expected (unpredictable behavior) due to the library replication..

Comment: Is it possible that you have two different classes loaded with `org.scribe.model.ParameterList` name? Because unwrapping the 3rd argument is a quite trivial case. The last important changes on this field were in 2.3.21 (2014-10-12), though it shouldn't cause regression like this.

Comment: I suspect that is the case, as I was having class def problems rather than class not found. But all the exceptions are now gone and if this was the case the methods before the assign would fail as well, correct?

Comment: For as much I see from the failing template, it might as well possible that `trueNTHConnect` uses another version of the problematic class than the methods called before it. Anyway, there's a sure way to find it out: modify FreeMarker at the places where the class names are printed so that it prints the identity hash of the `Class` objects too.

Comment: @ddekany Sorry for the long long time, I was browsing questions here and I noticed that this one was marked as unanswered. If you want, you can put in a answer..It solved the problem.

Comment: I have added this as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that you have two different classes loaded with `org.scribe.model.ParameterList` name. So `trueNTHConnect` uses another version of the problematic class than the methods called before it. The JVM will see them as totally different incompatible classes, hence there's no matching overload.

There's a sure way to find it out: debug or modify FreeMarker at the places where the class names are printed so that it prints the identity hash of the Class objects too.